# Labels don't redraw on Form.Refresh()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have a form on which in the Paint event some labels with some information are drawn inside a panel - this works fine. However I would like to have the text on the labels being changed depending on the value of a Trackbar that is placed on the same form. This is the Trackbar-Scroll Event which should refresh the whole form:

```
 Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

And this is the code that draws the labels on the form:

```
Public Sub Form_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)

    For i = 0 To 10

        Dim tb As New Label

        tb.Name = "tb" & CStr(i)
        If Me.TrackBar1.Value = 1 Then tb.Text = "sometext"
        If Me.TrackBar1.Value = 0 Then tb.Text = "anothertext"

        tb.Location = New Point(i, i * 2)

        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(tb)

    Next
End Sub
```

However no matter in what state the trackbar is the text displayed in the labels is alaways "anothertext". The Paint event is triggered as far as I can tell when I change the value of the trackbar but how can I also force the labels to update?

Comment: Are you intentionally adding 10 new labels every time the form paints?

Comment: @Plutonix 11 labels  ;)

Comment: Yes, 11; but the form paints more often than just when you call Refresh.  And that code is stacking this set on top of the old set so you only every see the most recent set

Comment: @Plutonix: It's not always 11 new labels, in the full code the number of labels, their possible contents and their position is stored in a datatable. Originally the drawing of the labels (and also lines connecting them) was not in the event but in a separate Sub, however this didn't work well so I moved it into the event.

Comment: @dunkleosteus This seems like an insane way to write a program.  You've chosen an architecture for this soluton that is terribly misguided.  Any possible amendment to it cannot reasonably infer what other crazy things you have going on that we cannot see.  From what we can see, this program will continue to consume memory until the system runs out and it crashes.  This whole approach is just wrong - everything about it.

Comment: Well, we can only go by the code you show us.  That code creates new labels every time the form paints and puts each set in the same location so only one set is ever seen.  The label text never changes, it is just that the new set may or may not have different text

Comment: Ok, I understand but what would be a good starting point to achieve what I'm trying to do? Simply take all the code that changes the labels' content (and/or position) out of the event and put it somewhere else?

Comment: We have no idea what you are trying to do - just **how** you are trying to do *something*.

Comment: At the very least you should remove the old labels before adding new ones. But the better solution is of course to draw directly onto the form, or add/update labels only when the data is actually updated (so not in the `Paint` event).

Comment: @Visual Vincent: thank you! removing the labels before the new ones are painted works just fine in this case. Originally I tried to do all the painting and setting labels outside of the paint event. But I'm also using System.Drawing.Pen to draw lines connecting the labels - this didn't work and I was told that I should try drawing in the Paint event (which eventually ended up in this problem)

Comment: Creating new labels that way rather than just updating 11 you add in the designer is *very expensive*.  Your app is very likely leaking resources now.  The paint event is a bad choice for data tracking

Comment: The only thing you should ever do in a paint event . . .  is paint something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the labels once. Separate the creating and changing logic into two methods

```
Private prefix As String = "tb"
Private factor As Integer = 10

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    addLabels()
    changeLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub addLabels()
    For i = 0 To 10
        Dim tb As New Label()
        tb.Name = prefix & CStr(i)
        tb.Location = New Point(factor * i, factor * i * 2)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(tb)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub changeLabels()
    For i = 0 To 10
        Dim tb As Label = CType(Panel1.Controls(prefix & CStr(i)), Label)
        If Me.TrackBar1.Value = 1 Then tb.Text = "sometext"
        If Me.TrackBar1.Value = 0 Then tb.Text = "anothertext"
    Next
End Sub
```

Now, in TrackBar1_Scroll, you can just change them (instead of recreating them)

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    changeLabels()
End Sub
```

Since the label value depends on the TrackBar value, there is no reason to update them in Paint, which happens more frequently than the TrackBar is updated.

Adding new Labels and removing old Labels in Paint seems like **a lot** of extra processing.

Comment: Thank you, I use a similar structure now and it does seem to work - only drawing lines with System.Drawing.Pen only seems to work in the Paint event.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need to set the LargeChange property of the TrackBar as a Scroll Event is considered a large change, but LargeChange defaults to 0, thus when you scroll the Value is only increasing/decreasing by 0, Leaving it at 0